# Why does my emulator not show anything despite no errors being shown?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm currently trying to figure out how to create a `ListView` together with a bottom navigation bar, however, though after running the emulator it did not show anything. Why is this so?

**This is my activity_main.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        app:menu="@menu/home"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**This is my nav_graph.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:name="sg.edu.rp.c346.a3pdwork.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/About"
        android:name="sg.edu.rp.c346.a3pdwork.AboutFragment"
        android:label="fragment_about"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Login"
        android:name="sg.edu.rp.c346.a3pdwork.LoginFragment"
        android:label="fragment_login"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" />
</navigation>
```

**This is my home.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_home"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Login"
        android:title="Login"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_login"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/About"
        android:title="About"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
        />

</menu>
```

**This is my fragment_home.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**This is my HomeFragment.java file**

```
package sg.edu.rp.c346.a3pdwork;


import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

}
```

**This is my fragment_login.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**This is my LoginFragment.java file**

```
package sg.edu.rp.c346.a3pdwork;


import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {


    public LoginFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    }

}
```

**This is my fragment_about.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AboutFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**This is my AboutFragment.java file**

```
package sg.edu.rp.c346.a3pdwork;


import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {


    public AboutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
    }

}
```

**This is my MainActivity.java file**

```
package sg.edu.rp.c346.a3pdwork;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,
                R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
      NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNav, navController);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruchin.
Wish you many good things to come with android developing.

In this situation I've got 2 things to tell you:

**First:** Your `BottomNavigationView` has no `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes. I think you just forgot to put them in here (if so, it is not any problem, I just wanted to make sure you notice that).

**Second:** Your layout is shown correctly. Why you see nothing? Because you have two views `TextView` and `ListView` which have `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. So at first `TextView` is rendered and then `ListView` is rendered on it.

How can you see some results? That's simple. Just change `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout`, set `orientation` to `vertical` and set **TextView**'s height to `wrap_content`. You can put these changes in your **fragment_home.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping! But after making the respective changes though, it keeps crashing, am i missing out something else?

Comment: @Ruchin Sorry it was my fault. You should set an orientation for your `LinearLayout` like this: `android:orientation="vertical"`.

Comment: no error is detected from the android studio, its just that when i run the emulator the app keeps crashing, im guessing that it has to be related to these 3 lines written in the logcat?

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/sg.edu.rp.c346.a3pdwork-2ST4X0kMLHd7NTO0CfzMVA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/sg.edu.rp.c346.a3pdwork-2ST4X0kMLHd7NTO0CfzMVA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]

Comment: Sorry idk why stack overflow dont allow me to insert all 3 together

Comment: @Ruchin it's because you didn't set `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to your `BottomNavigationView` in `activity_main.xml` file.